# Chaining apply to bind. Why do I need to pad my array with 1 extra value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, this, apply, bind

I was breaking down some code I found.  I got stuck on a specific issue and managed to break it down into a smaller piece.  Just keep in mind that this code is part of a much bigger piece of code.

```
function foo(string, num) {
    console.log("calling foo ---", string, num);
}
```

This following bit looks like it should work.  I pass my two arguments into the array that's passed into apply.

But as you can see by the comment I added.  The `num` parameter is `undefined`.  And the `string` parameter has the second value in the array I passed in, which was intended to be the for `num`.

```
foo.bind.apply(foo, ["fdsf", 432])(); // calling foo --- 432 undefined
```

But if I add an additional value at the beginning of the array (it could be anything), Then everything works smoothly.

```
foo.bind.apply(foo, [0, "fdsf", 432])(); // calling foo --- fdsf 432
```

Can anyone please shed some light on what's happening here?  If I call `bind` or `apply` separately, the array padding is not needed.  It only seems to be needed when combining them.

Why is the additional value at the beginning of the array needed?

Also, here is the original code for reference.  It's from one of Kyle Simpsons books.

```
function asyncify(fn) {
    var orig_fn = fn,
        intv = setTimeout( function(){
            intv = null;
            if (fn) fn();
        }, 0 );

    fn = null;

    return function() {
        if (intv) {
            fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(orig_fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
        } else {
            orig_fn.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    };
}
```

There's a lot more going on here.  But inside the `if` statement about 2/3's though the code, you can see it.

The second argument for apply is the array, with the first value (the padding) being the `global` object (I'm assuming it's the global object, it's not important, it could be anything). followed by any of the arguments that were passed in.

Some of that extra bit is just turning the arguments array-like object into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument that `bind` accepts is the `this` value to be used inside the function. So, if you use

```
fn.bind.apply(fn, arr)
```

the first item of the `arr` becomes the first argument of bind, eg, it's equivalent to:

```
fn.bind(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] /* ... */ )
```

So the first item of the array becomes the `this` value, the second item of the array becomes the first argument, the third item of the array becomes the second argument, etc.

Here's a live example of how "padding" the array with a value at the start becomes the new `this` value when the function is called:

```js
const obj = { prop: 'val' };

function foo(string, num) {
    console.log("calling foo ---", string, num);
    console.log('this:', this);
}

const fn = foo.bind.apply(foo, [obj, 'str', 55]);
fn();
```

As for the repetitive nature of

```
foo.bind.apply(foo, ...
```

It's necessary to repeat the function name when calling `apply` so that when `bind` is called, it's called with the right calling context - the `this` value used when `.bind` is called is how `.bind` knows which function to bind. (The first argument passed to `.apply`, just like `.call`, is the `this` value to be used in the function being applied)

Comment: Oh I get it now.  That makes sense.  Thank you so much!